# Use source files in different directory in NetBeans Dynamic Library Project

Tags: c++, dll, netbeans, vtk

I am new to C++ and NetBeans and I am trying to build a Dynamic Library project using it :). I want to build a plugin which uses source files located in different directories, and would like to keep them separately (as its a plugin ;)). I already tried to include the directory where the source files are located using Properties > Build > C++ Compiler > Include Directories, but it still gives errors in referencing to these files. These errors say the following:

"Cannot find include file "vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h" "

Can anyone help me on this? I assume its a bit of a basic-basic-basic question, but I'm trying to learn autodidactically as a geologist from background, so you might see my problem :). I really hope you can help me out! Thanks :)

Ellen

Comment: Can you give us a small example, especially some `#include` directives you use and an overview about your directory- and project structure?

Comment: My structure looks like the following: two separate folders within C:/ so like the folder C:/paraview-source and C:/exampleplugin. The exampleplugin contains the header- and sourcefiles for the plugin which point towards header- and sourcefiles within the paraview folder as well, e.g. the standard headerfile #include "vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h". Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

While your way is the default way to add directories which contain additional headers (e.g. for libraries), you can add further Source-directories using **`Properties -> General -> Source Folders (-> Add)`**.

It's also possible to add files (cpp / h) to your project, without setting a directory:

**`Right click on your project -> Add existing item ...`** or **`Add existing items from folders ...`**

But you have to care about your paths, you may have to browse to the headers using `#include "../headers/here/example.h`.

Comment: I tried the first option, but it does not seem to help. I added the general Paraview source code folder as a source. Or should I point to the exact subfolder inside this source code? I tried that as well, but still the header file is not recognized, although i'm not sure whether it's taking the directory in the right way..

Comment: Can you show an example `#include` like its set in your code? If you type `#include ".."`, what does autocomplete show?

Comment: The autocomplete shows:

>Unresolved directive
#include "vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h" 
Analyzed user include paths:
\\PARAVIEW\ParaView-v4.0.1.-source
Analyzed system include paths:
here it mentions al MinGW paths including c++ and include files
Include path trail to current file:
\\Paraview_projects\ExamplePluginPV\MyReader.cxx: (line 1)


Hope this helps? Thanks :)

Comment: Please check something like `#include "../../paraview-source/headers/vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h"` (browsing through `..` is set according to your path).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but than you have to set those paths until very deep into the structure (which I did not prepare myself..). I was wondering if something with right-mouse-click > Properties > Linker could work? Would you give it a change?

Comment: Normal you can add additional paths through **`Properties -> General -> Source Folders`** (as above), so it's really strange, that this fails for you.

Comment: You can use those linker settings if you have already compiled libraries, but for adding code (source files), the linker is the wrong place. Btw. what version of NB are you using?

Comment: NB 7.3.1. May this be a problem? I already thought it is weird myself.. Thanks again.

Comment: No, this version is fine. Btw. do you have any blanks in one of the paths?

Comment: Ehm no, not that I know. I'm a bit running out of ideas, but got the task to focus a bit on other things right now. Thanks for your help anyways, may come back to this later :).

Comment: If you have some time, you may have a look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) - i think this may be a good alternative, capable to solve your problem. And: NetBeans supports CMake projects, so you can stay with NB - only the build tool is another one.

Comment: Thanks Ollo! Actually, I was planning to use CMake as I want to write some Paraview plugins :)